# Don't pee there! Device

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, hardware

I want to make a device with a sensor I can attach to the places my dog likes to mark. When sensor becomes wet I want a buzzer to make a loud noise to scare the animal and notify me I need to encourage the dog to go outside. Any suggestions on what sensor to use.

Comment: [rain sensor](http://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-Modules-Rain-Sensor/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably will want a moisture sensor like [this one](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/like/370999421770?limghlpsr=true&hlpv=2&ops=true&viphx=1&hlpht=true&lpid=108&chn=ps&device=c&adtype=pla&crdt=0&ff3=1&ff11=ICEP3.0.0-L&ff12=67&ff13=80&ff14=108) (there are many variations of this).

This will return one signal when dry, and another when wet.

You will need a Buzzer to make a sound as well (Or a piezo speaker if you feel like getting more advanced) in order to make a sound.

Your sketch should have, in its `loop`, an `if` statement checking if the moisture sensor has returned the wet signal (The signal will depend on the sensor you get) and, in the block that executes if there is a signal, a statement driving the buzzer and a delay before turning it off.

Bear in mind that you want to keep the Arduino itself away from the moisture sensor, as your Arduino probably won't survive the dog's doings.